# Need explanation of a matrix multiplication

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, linear-algebra

I'm reading the Deep Learning book by MIT.
On the page 172, there's a part like this:
$$
f^{(1)}(x)=h=W^Tx  \tag{1}
$$
$$
f^{(2)}(h)=h^Tw \tag{2}
$$
Substitute (1) into (2), they got:
$$
f(x)=w^TW^Tx
$$
Since I'm not so familiar with linear algebra stuff, I infer that something like below is valid:
$$
A^TB=B^TA \tag{3}
$$
So what is the property of (3) is called?

Comment: Please formulate the question that everyone is able to understand it. Nobody is familiar with every book there is. Please state the problem and add short descriptions to variable, so we know, what they denote. Have a nice stay and welcome to the community ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's take it step by step.

$$
f^{(1)}(x)=h=W^Tx  \tag{1}
$$

$$
f^{(2)}(h)=h^Tw \tag{2}
$$

We substitute `h`.

$$
f(x)=(W^Tx)^Tw   \tag{3}
$$

To make it work, we'll make a little trick.

> The transpose of a transposed matrix is the original matrix.

$$
(A^T)^T = A
$$

We substitute `w`.

$$
f(x)=(W^Tx)^T (w^T)^T  \tag{4}
$$

Now we use following:

$$
(AB)^T=B^T A^T
$$

> The transpose of two matrices multiplied together is the same as the product of their transpose matrices in reverse order.

et voila

$$
f(x)=w^TW^Tx
$$

Comment: Actually the final formula should be transposed. But I guess it's just a vector, not an array, so who cares?

Comment: Thanks! That work!

Comment: No problem ;) Now gimme that juicy thumbs up and accept the answer ;p

Comment: Too bad! My thumbs are invisible!